# SD card example freezes at line SD.begin() what should I do?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, sd-card

I have a 16GB SD card which is formated with FAT32. I'm trying to run the example codes presented for SD in Arduino. The SD card is inserted in the data logging shield and the CS pin in this shield is connected to pin 10.
I first tried the Cardinfo example and this is the result:
[image: Serial Output of Cardinfo]

The SD card is not empty, there exist a few files in it but this example was unable to show this files.
I then tried the example ReadWrite and the code freezes on line SD.begin(10).
I have no Idea where this problem is coming from.

Comment: try the card without files on it

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. The Cardinfo example can detect it but can't read the system file. The ReadWrite example freezes on SD.begin() line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when I used a big SD card, maybe because some cards have a more modern format.

If you have smaller / older cards, try them and see if those work; than you rule out it is not a circuit/connection problem.

Comment: It is difficult to find an SD with lower capacities. But I search maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I think I had that problem about 2 years ago too when I tried a bigger SD card.

Comment: I found another SD card with 16GB capacity, but fortunately, it worked!

Comment: Good to hear your problem is solved ... maybe the smaller SD card I tried has the same properties as your working card ... still wondering what the exact specifications should be.. But glad you found one that worked.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I found another SD with 16GB capacity, and fortunately it worked. So the problem was because of the SD but I don't know what was the exact problem. I post the photo of this SD cards.

[image]